# F#,correct usage of split method

Tags: string, split, f#

How do i use the split method in f# correctly?

The code:

```
    let a = "abc def" 

let b = a.Split [|' '|]

Console.WriteLine("{0}", b)
```

does return

```
 "System.String[]"
```

i tryed many variations of:

```
 .Split([|' '|])
```

The language doc & other questions don't really help.

i want b to be:

```
 ["abc","def"]
```

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a list as result but `.Split` returns an array of strings, not a list of strings.

If you want a list just call `Array.toList` after calling `.Split`:

```
let b = a.Split [|' '|] |> Array.toList
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments, if you are happy with the result as an Array then all you need to change is the way you print it.

One way is to use `sprintf` to *pretty-print* the array, as stated in my comments and in the other answer. Here's another way:

```
open System

let a = "abc def" 
let b = a.Split [|' '|]

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(";", b))
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply in my case it looks like it does not return anything just the "System.String[]" is outputed. how do i change the code so that the output is the array where "abc" "def" are some of the entrys

Comment: It returns a proper value. It's the way you print it. Remove the Console.WriteLine and try it in FSI. Or use Console.WriteLine(sprintf "%A" b)

Answer (score 5):

Your `Console.WriteLine` is the actual problem here, not the fact you get an array vs a list. It's just that the list overrides `ToString`, so that happens to make your code work.

You can use either of these to get the same effect with an array:

```
Console.WriteLine(sprintf "%A" b)
printfn "%A" b
```